# how does lambda expression take argument

Tags: c++, function, oop, lambda, overloading

I am wondering how does a lambda expression take its arguments?

Usually, when we pass variables into parameters, we need to match the number of arguments and number of variables. for example, for regular function `void foo(int a, int b)` we need to pass two `int` variables to the functions.

However, with lambda expression we don't need to do it. for example:

```cpp
sort(intContainer.begin(), intContainer.end(), [](int i, int j){return i>j;});
```

This function will sort the container in descending order.

I am wondering how the lambda expression takes `int j` argument. (when I assume that one iterator holds one int value taking variable for int i is makes sense)
does it related with the way how an iterator works??

Comment: I think you are asking about the details of `std::sort` more than _lambdas_.  The "comparison object" passed to `std::sort` does not have to be a lambda.  It could be a function, or anything that satifies the [compare predicate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: A lambda expression is an abbreviated way to create a functor.  Very related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: You seem to think that the lambda is called with one argument here? Why is that? It's not called in the line you're showing us; `std::sort` calls it internally (with two arguments).

Comment: You can use https://cppinsights.io/ to see how a lambda looks: [here is yours](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=aW50IG1haW4oKSB7CiAgICBhdXRvIGNvbXAgPSBbXShpbnQgaSwgaW50IGopIHsgcmV0dXJuIGkgPiBqOyB9Owp9&std=cpp17&rev=1.0)

Comment: _"How does std::sort provide the two parameters that are passed to my lambda?"_ Is that a valid rephrasing of what your question is?